# React js component not listen to Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to collaborate react with jquery as below

suppose I have this textarea that produce by react

```
var textarea = React.createClass({
   render : function(){
       return <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>;
   }
});
```

I want this textarea autosize by applying a plugin called "autosize", so I did this;

```
$("#mytextarea").autosize();

ReactDOM.render(<textarea/>, document.getElementById('form'));
```

note : If I make normal textarea (not by react DOM compoenent), the plugin work.
but not with react component.

Comment: try instead of id, using `className="mytextarea"` and `".mytextarea"` for jQuery

Answer (score 2):

The textarea is not rendered at the time you are calling `$("#mytextarea").autosize();`, so it doesn't actually exist yet. You might be successful in calling `.autosize()` in React's `componentDidMount()` method, which will be called after your component is rendered.

```
var textarea = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $("#mytextarea").autosize();
  },
  render : function(){
    return <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>;
  }
});
```